# Unrecognized selector sent to instance when UIPageViewController.dataSource is set?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am attempting to programmatically create a page view in a subview. However, when I set the dataSource of the UIPageViewController to the superviewcontroller, I get this error:

```
-[UIView scrollView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc223ea8300
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView scrollView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc223ea8300'
```

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
class MainVC: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    private var pages: [UIViewController]
    private let pageVC: UIPageViewController
    init() {
        pages = [UIViewController]()
        for i in 0...1 {
            let vc = UIViewController()
            vc.view = MyUIViewSubclass(index: i)
            pages.append(vc)
        }
        pageVC = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
        pageVC.view = UIView()
        pageVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        pageVC.dataSource = self //Breakpoints indicate that this is when the exception occurs
        view.addSubview(pageVC.view)
        //...Autolayout...
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return pages[0]
    }
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return pages[1]
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add any scrollview on your view?

Comment: @S.Karthik No, `MyUIViewSubclass` only has buttons on it. I believe the scrollView message has to do with `transitionStyle: .Scroll`.

Comment: I have the same issue in the exact same line of code, and of course I'm using the same approach (to separate code into view, delegates and controller) 
Did you found any solution??

Answer (score 0):

The pageVc.view has an ibaction named scrollview that is not declared in your view controller,you need to remove the ibaction from connections inspector

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I had the same problem as you, and I found out why it's happening.
The error happens because of the line where you do `pageVC.view = UIView()`.
The UIPageViewController's view has a scroll view, where the magic of scrolling between VCs happen. By setting an empty UIView to it, you're removing it, not making it possible to work. If you'd like to change something to its view you should do it directly, not setting another one.